# Finding $\int_{C}a\ dz$, where $C$ is the contour $z(\theta) = \rho e^{i\theta}$ for $\theta\in[-\pi,\pi]$.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, complex-integration

I have been working with some complex integrations but I would like to know if I am right about this simple integration:

> **Question :** For complex plane: let $C$ be the contour $z(\theta) = \rho e^{i\theta}$ for $(-\pi\leq\theta\leq\pi)$ and let $a$ and $\rho$ be any constant. Find $\displaystyle\int_{C}a\ \mathrm{d}z\ .$

**My Attempt**

$$\int_{C}a\,\mathrm{d}z = \int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} a \rho\ ie^{i\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta,$$  (where we make a variable change for $z$ s.t $\mathrm{d}z = \rho\ ie^{i\theta}\ \mathrm{d}\theta$).

$$= a \rho i\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{i\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta\\
= a \rho i \cdot\frac{e^{i\theta}}{i}\bigg|_{-\pi}^{\pi}\\
= 2a \rho $$

does this look right?

Comment: $e^{i\pi}=e^{-i\pi}=-1$ so you should get $0$ as the answer.

Comment: @Kyky, thank you for your reply. I see that I mistakenly let $cos(\pi) = 1$ when it should have been $-1$ when converting to polar form. So other than that the integration is correct?

Comment: Note that $\int_C a \, dz$ is zero for *any* closed path in $\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to see that you made a mistake, because a constant function $f(z)=a$ is analytic, and you are integrating around a closed curve.  By Cauchy's theorem the integral is then zero.

It was right until you forgot that $e^{iπ}=e^{-iπ}$.

Comment: Cauchy's theorem is far too heavy machinery for this purpose. The integral over any closed curve of a constant (or more generally, of a derivative) is trivially zero.

Comment: If the OP doesn't have Cauchy's theorem yet, they will soon.  @MartinR  Frankly, what's the difference?  Cauchy's theorem is more memorable anyway.

Comment: $\int_{C}a\, dz = 0$ follows immediately from the definition. Cauchy's theorem is a deep theorem about integrals on simply-connected domains.

Comment: Like I said.   Point taken. @MartinR

Comment: What if the domain was $C^*$?

Comment: That is exactly my point. If $D \subset \Bbb C$ is an arbitrary domain, $f$ complex differentiable in $D$, and $C$ an arbitrary curve in $D$, then $\int_C f'(z) dz = 0$. (A complex analogue of the real fundamental theorem of calculus). – On the other hand, Cauchy's theorem $\int_C f(z) dz = 0$ is only applicable if the domain is simply-connected, or if the curve is null-homotopic.

Comment: Right.   I see your point.   But for someone who forgets some of the basics,  Cauchy's theorem is something I never forget.   I did play right into your hands there.  Touche.